# Connecting to a switch?

Tags: switch, serial-port, arch-linux

I have a managed switch that I liberated from our school's surplus goods store for $10 that has a serial based console. I have a serial cable and a computer with a serial port, but I have no idea what protocol to use to connect between the two. I'm running Arch Linux on the computer with the serial port. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a serial terminal program, such as [CuteCom](http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: no. but i will right after this.

Comment: If you write a comment starting with `@sblair` he/she will be notified of that comment next time they visit superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a serial terminal program, such as [CuteCom](http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/)?